# All possible combinations for a BIG array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I am trying for 2 days to create a function to get all possible array combinations (without order repetitions):

```
 public function power_set($array) {
    // initialize by adding the empty set
    $results = array(array( ));

    foreach ($array as $element)
        foreach ($results as $combination)
            array_push($results, array_merge($combination,array($element)));

    return $results;
}

$keys = array(0=>1,1=>2,3=>3,21=>4,4=>5,5=>6,6=>7,7=>8,9=>10,10=>23,11=>34234,12=>34234,13=>34234,14=>45435,15=>32343,16=>35324,17=>4535345,18=>5645645,19=>234,20=>23324);

 echo '<pre>'.print_r(power_set($keys),true).'</pre>';
```

It work fine for a 7 element array, but more than than it dont't. How can I fix it?

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: you want to remove duplicate?

Comment: I want all possible combinations of array values

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo BTW: OP gets a notification if you post an answer, so no need for this comment ^. And for your information and for the future: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253835/3933332

Comment: @JohnMark Can you please add your current output and your expected output. (Maybe with a smaller array :D)

Comment: for array(1,2,3); I want a output of array(1),array(2),array(3),array(1,2),array(1,3), array(2,3) and array(1,2,3). Try my funtion, it will work. Just dont work with big sets. Maybe I ll slice the array.

Comment: The array you give as parameter of the function is messy, can you explain what is it? Anyway for large arrays it gives me a fatal error: `Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) on line 7` (array_push() function)

Answer (score 0):

John I think this is more of an issue with where you are running the code.  As some of the comments on your question indicate, the php shell where you are executing the function has a limited working memory.

I tested with an array length 10, and was returned 1024 items (the correct amount).

Try running it as a file in your console:  `$ php test_file.php`

Comment: I ll try. But try it with 20 or 30 elements. It will be a lot of repetitions and maybe it will run out of memory. I am trying to find a way to resolve it, maybe with array_chunk and dividing the loop jobs with different calls.

Comment: Yeah, broke around 18-ish for me...  What are you trying to do here anyway?  You should reformat your question to make it clear that this is a working memory problem and not a program functionality issue.